# How do I add a third column to my current coding?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I'd like to add a third column into my page but I'm not sure how to do so without editing my current code; is there a way to do so?
(I'm really not the best at coding I apologize for those of you who are face-palming).

This is my current code:

```css
#header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
#nav {
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
#section {
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
#footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
#aside {
  width: 350px;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <u><h1 style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">Search Engines</h1></u>
</div>

<div id="nav">
  <a href="http://www.excite.co.uk/">Excite</a>
  <br>
  <a href="http://www.google.co.uk/">Google</a>
  <br>
  <a href="http://www.yahoo.co.uk/">Yahoo</a>
  <br>
  <a href="http://www.bing.co.uk/">Bing</a>
  <br>
  <a href="http://www.askjeeves.co.uk/">AskJeeves</a>
  <br>
  <a href="http://www.duckduckgo.com/">DuckDuckGo</a>
  <br>
  <a href="http://www.aol.co.uk/">Aol</a>
  <br>
  <a href="http://www.wolframalpha.co.uk/">Wolfram Alpha</a>
  <br>
  <a href="http://www.overture.com/">Overture</a>
  <br>
</div>

<div id="section">
  <u><h2 style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">What is a Search Engine?</h2></u>
  <p style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">
    Search engines are special websites that have indexed billions of pages - and make it easy for you to find a website or page in an instant. Popular search engines include Google, Yahoo!, Bing and Ask.
    <p style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">
      To get to a search engine you just need to go to your browser's address bar and type in the address of the search engine website, or you can use the search box that's usually found in the top right-hand corner of a browser.
    </p>
</div>

<div id="aside">
  <u><h2 style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">How do Search Engines Work?</h2></u>
  <p style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">Each search engine works in a similar way. If you go to a search engine's homepage, you'll find a single box. You simply type whatever you want to search for into that box.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  Zoe is a fabulous human being.
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Susan! I'd suggest creating a JSFiddle to show your functioning problem. Here's your code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/azov2c0q/

Comment: Also, any code you can post here would be very helpful.  Lots of people would rather start at code here than go to another location (even a fiddle).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to change it to three columns.
I have modified your code.

1. I have deleted the css for #section and #aside.
2. I have modified some of the css properties for #nav
3. I have created a css class called .column which is applied to your #section/#aside and the third column that I have created.

Html:

```
<div id="header">
<u><h1 style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">Search Engines</h1><u>
</div>

<div id="nav">
<a href="http://www.excite.co.uk/">Excite</a><br>
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk/">Google</a><br>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.co.uk/">Yahoo</a><br>
<a href="http://www.bing.co.uk/">Bing</a><br>
<a href="http://www.askjeeves.co.uk/">AskJeeves</a><br>
<a href="http://www.duckduckgo.com/">DuckDuckGo</a><br>
<a href="http://www.aol.co.uk/">Aol</a><br>
<a href="http://www.wolframalpha.co.uk/">Wolfram Alpha</a><br>
<a href="http://www.overture.com/">Overture</a><br>
</div>

<div class="column">
<u><h2 style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">First Column</h2></u>
<p style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">
Search engines are special websites that have indexed billions of pages - and make it easy for you to find a website or page in an  instant.
 Popular search engines include Google, Yahoo!, Bing and Ask.
<p style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">
To get to a search engine you just need to go to your browser's address bar and type in the address of the search engine website,
 or you can use the search box that's usually found in the top right-hand corner of a browser.
</p>
</div>

<div class="column">
<u><h2 style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">Second Column</h2></u>
<p style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">Each search engine works in a similar way. If you go to a search engine's homepage,
 you'll find a single box. You simply type whatever you want to search for into that box.</p>
</div>

<div class="column">
<u><h2 style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">Third Column</h2></u>
<p style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:center">Each search engine works in a similar way. If you go to a search engine's homepage,
 you'll find a single box. You simply type whatever you want to search for into that box.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
Zoe is a fabulous human being.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;

    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:10%;
}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
   padding:5px;          
}

.column{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width: 30%;
  float:left;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Here is the codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgEmwJ

Edit: This solution is a brief one, it does not catter for very small screen sizes. You can try re-sizing your browser's width; you'll notice if the width of browser is too small, the width of your nav-bar may not be enough for its content.

This is when you might want to look into media queries and define another set of css rules for small viewports